# What's the difference between . and (.) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a pipeline function that rolls an value through a list of functions from the right. The function looks like this:

```
map . foldr (.) id
```

But I don't understand what is it doing here? I do know that `.` is function composition, but what does `(.)` do?

Comment: Note that `.` isn't some kind of special, built-in feature of Haskell. It's a normal operator [defined in the usual way](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between `.` and `(.)` is the same as that between `+` and `(+)`, `-` and `(-)`, and all the others:

- without parenthesis you have the [infix form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator), for which you put the operands right before and after the symbol, as in `f . g` or `3 + 5`;
- with the parenthesis you have the function application form, for which the operands go both after the function name, as in `(.) f g` or `(+) 3 5`.

Something similar is true also for functions with "normal" names, such as `myfunc`. In this case, however, the plain name `myfunc` wants the arguments after it (just like `(.)`), and the infix form is obtained by putting the name between backticks.

Here are a few equalities as examples:

```hs
f . g === (.) f g
a + b === (+) a b
a `fun` b === fun a b
i `elem` l === elem i l
```

As an additional info, even if a function takes more than 2 arguments, as in

```hs
func x y z = whatever
```

you can still call it with infix style, but writing `` a `func` b `` will give you a function taking one argument (the one corresponding to `z`), just like you had done `func a b`. (This is [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application). Example: `f = (+) 3` is valid and it results in a function `f` that adds 3 to whichever argument you pass to it, e.g. `f 5 == 8`.)

Comment: @JiaqiShao, no, I didn't mean that. `(+) 3`, for instance, is valid and it results in a function that adds 3 to whichever argument you pass to it. This is [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application). I strongly suggest that you spend some time studying the basics of Haskell. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a good book to start with.

Answer (score 3):

As @Enlico has already said in their answer, the form `.` without parentheses is an infix operator. By contrast, the form `(.)` with parentheses refers to the *function* `(.)` which takes two other functions as arguments and returns their composition.

To illustrate how this applies to your example, consider the four possible variations you might try:

1. `map . foldr . id`
2. `map . foldr (.) id`
3. `map (.) foldr . id`
4. `map (.) foldr (.) id`

These look pretty similar at first. But placing parentheses around the function applications reveals the differences:

1. `map . foldr . id`
2. `map . (foldr (.) id)`
3. `(map (.) foldr) . id`
4. `(map (.) foldr (.) id)`

In words: variation (1) runs `id`, then applies `foldr` to its result, then applies `map` to the result of that. Evidently this is fairly useless, not least because composition with `id` does nothing. Variation (2) is what you have: it folds a list using function composition — i.e. using the function `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` — with a base case of `id`, before passing the result of this as the first argument of `map`, thereby mapping this newly composed function over a list. Variation (3), on the other hand, is not only meaningless but badly written to boot: not only does it evaluate `map (.) foldr`, an expression which doesn’t even typecheck, it then attempts to compose it with `id`, which as I already mentioned does nothing. Finally, variation (4) applies the function `map` — which as we all know only takes two arguments at most — to four arguments, namely the functions `(.)`, `foldr`, `(.)` and `id`. Clearly, variation (2), which is what you have, is the only one here which makes sense.